# ExtJS: How to change component `labelStyle` within a function?

Tags: javascript, extjs, colors, label, overriding

**tl/dr**:
There is not any `setter` for `labelStyle`. So how can I change it's value on a function?

I've a `afterrender` listener and aim to set color of `fieldLabel` as white and set a `emptyText` instead of `fieldLabel` and *meanwhile I need to change `fieldLabel` color to be white*! So I need to access current component's `lableStyle` property. I've try to go within `config` but couldn't find it. As well tried to use `Ext.apply()` to set a property for related combo but this is not work either.

How can I achieve my aim over here?

```
//Related component `listeners`;
listeners   : {
        afterrender: 'removeLabel',
        focusenter: 'createLabel'
    },

//Related function;
removeLabel: function () {
        let formComponent = ['foocombobox', 'bartextfield', 'zetdatefield'];

        Ext.each(formComponent, function (eachComp) {
            let currentComp = Ext.ComponentQuery.query(eachComp)[0];

            if (currentComp.value === '')) {
                let currentLabel = currentComp.fieldLabel;
                currentComp.setEmptyText(currentLabel);

                //This can not work because of I've reach constructor config. So how can I reach?
                //currentComp.labelStyle  = "color:red;";

                //I tried to manipulate through Ext.apply but did not effect;
                //Ext.apply(currentComp, {labelStyle: "color:red;"});


            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extjs How can I change the 'style' of Ext.form.Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036429/extjs-how-can-i-change-the-style-of-ext-form-label)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get dom node by `currentComp.labelTextEl.dom` and then run `setAttribute` function:
[**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lra)

```
if (!currentComp.value) {
    urrentComp.setEmptyText(currentComp.fieldLabel);
    currentComp.labelTextEl.dom.setAttribute('style', 'color:white;'); 
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.